# sql server comma delimted string values into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sapb1

I have a query that returns a row of multiple `Itemcodes`. The result is

```
   Date        group      list of item code
  2015-04-15    118       FYCT-00063,FYCM-00016,FYCM-00064,FYCF-00018
```

it's working fine but i need the result like this, with quotes around every      code `'FYCT-00063','FYCM-00016','FYCM-00064','FYCF-00018'`

The query is this:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT SS.PostDate,SS.U_Unit,STUFF((
      SELECT ', ',+   CAST(OWOR.ItemCode AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
     FROM OWOR
     WHERE OWOR.PostDate=SS.PostDate AND OWOR.U_Unit=SS.U_Unit AND       OWOR.Status=SS.Status
  FOR XML PATH('') , TYPE)
  .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') LISTGroup 
  from owor SS
  Where SS.PostDate='15.APRIL.15' AND SS.U_Unit='Unit No 2' and SS.Status!='C'
```

Comment: What are you using the result set for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT SS.PostDate
    ,SS.U_Unit
    ,STUFF((
            SELECT ', '
                + QUOTENAME(CAST(OWOR.ItemCode AS VARCHAR(10), ''''))
            FROM OWOR
            WHERE OWOR.PostDate = SS.PostDate
                AND OWOR.U_Unit = SS.U_Unit
                AND OWOR.STATUS = SS.STATUS
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, ' ') LISTGroup
FROM owor SS
WHERE SS.PostDate = '15.APRIL.15'
    AND SS.U_Unit = 'Unit No 2'
    AND SS.STATUS != 'C'
```

Comment: its give the error with + concatenate operator can i give u remote session

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT SS.PostDate,SS.U_Unit,
    STUFF((
           SELECT ', ',+ '''' + CAST(OWOR.ItemCode AS VARCHAR(10) + '''') [text()]
           FROM OWOR
           WHERE OWOR.PostDate=SS.PostDate 
           AND OWOR.U_Unit=SS.U_Unit 
           AND OWOR.Status=SS.Status
    FOR XML PATH('') , TYPE) .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') LISTGroup 
FROM owor SS
WHERE SS.PostDate='15.APRIL.15' 
AND SS.U_Unit='Unit No 2' 
AND SS.Status!='C'
```

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'text()'.  ITS GIVE ME THE ERROR

Comment: try now, added extra '

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
DECLARE @STRING varchar(max) 
SELECT @STRING = 'FYCT-00063,FYCM-00016,FYCM-00064,FYCF-00018'

SELECT '''' + REPLACE(@STRING,',',''',''') + ''''
```

**[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/4714)**

In your case it would be like

```
select distinct SS.PostDate,SS.U_Unit,'''' + REPLACE(STUFF((
  SELECT ', ',+   CAST(OWOR.ItemCode AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
  FROM OWOR
  where OWOR.PostDate=SS.PostDate AND OWOR.U_Unit=SS.U_Unit AND OWOR.Status=SS.Status
  FOR XML PATH('') , TYPE)
  .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' '),',',''',''') + '''' LISTGroup 
  from owor SS
  Where SS.PostDate='15.APRIL.15' AND SS.U_Unit='Unit No 2' and SS.Status!='C'
```

Comment: @SafeerKhan:- You are welcome. You can accept the answer. A right tick mark turns green when clicked